# Prove if a function $f_k$ is convergent to $f$ in $L^2$, then $\hat{f}_k$ converges to $\hat{f}$ in $C$

Tags: analysis, convergence-divergence

The full question is as follows:
Let $f_k, f \in C(\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}; \mathbb{C}), k = 1, 2, ...$. Show that if the $f_k$ converge to $f$ in $L^2$, then for every integer $n$, the sequence of complex numbers $(\hat{f}_k(n))^\infty\_{k=1}$ converges to $\hat{f}(n)$ in $\mathbb{C}$.

I understand I have to use Cauchy-Schwarz to solve, but I don't know what to use for my inequality. I've tried $\hat{f}_k(n)\leq | \langle f_k(n),e_n \rangle|^2\leq \langle f_k,f_k \rangle* \langle e_n,e_n \rangle = \Vert f_k \Vert_2$ in an attempt to get somewhere, but I know that isn't right.

Comment: You should use "\langle" and "\rangle" for $\langle$ and $\rangle$ also you can use "\Vert" to write the norm $\Vert$ and "\vert" for the absolute value bars $\vert $

Comment: @Alibibi if the answer below was helpful, see: [How do I accept an answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/how-do-i-accept-an-answer)

Answer (score 1):

You have
$$
\begin{align*}
\left| \hat{ f_k} _{ } ( n) - \hat{ f}( n)   \right| 
&= \left|\frac{1}{ 2\pi }  \int_{ -\pi }^{ \pi }(  f _{ k} ( x)- f _{ }( x)   )e^{ -in x} \,dx\right| 
\\ 
&\leqslant \frac{1}{ 2\pi } \int_{ -\pi }^{ \pi } \left| f _{ k} ( x)  - f ( x) \right| \, dx 
\\ 
&\leqslant   \int_{ -\pi }^{ \pi } \left| f _{ k} ( x) - f( x) \right| ^{ 2}\, dx = \left\| f _{ k}  - f\right\|_{ L^{2}([-\pi, \pi])} \stackrel{ k \to \infty }{\longrightarrow} 0
.\end{align*}
$$

Comment: Why is it $\frac{1}{2\pi}$ and from $-\pi$ to $\pi$? My professor uses 0 to 1 for all periodic functions. Does it matter?

Comment: It indeed doesn't matter, the argument above works the same in your case.